# An error occurred while installing refile (0.6.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I can't install refile gem from cloned repo on my local.

in my Gemfile:

```
gem "refile", require: "refile/rails"
gem "refile-mini_magick"
```

and after running `bundle install --without production`

i got this error:
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Did you define `ruby 2.2.3` in Gemfile?

Comment: Now i did and got this error: Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3. i don't understand why still v 2.0.0 since i upgraded it with rvm

Comment: Are you using rvm? or rbenv?

Comment: I used rvm to upgrade. as you can see in the screenshot when i run 'ruby -v' it shows me that the version is 2.2.3 and when specify required version '2.2.3' in the Gemfile the error says 'Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3.' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check ruby current and default version. `rvm list`
2. Make default your ruby 2.2.3 version `rvm use 2.2.3 --default`
3. Close terminal and go back to your project directory.